# Is there a class/archetype/prestige class/feat that can absorb the lifeforce of an enemy to fuel its power?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, evil-campaign

Pretty clear: I am going to do an evil character in an evil campaign, and I like the idea of using the life of my enemies to fuel my power.

I am looking for anything that turn an enemy into a resource other than creating undead (but it can be an option).

Comment: there are a LOT of things that draw power from enemies, up to and including consuming their soul for power in a wide variety of ways.  Are you looking for a list of all the things that fit with this or is there some way we'd be able to tell what options are better than others?  If you want a full list, I think a forum might be a better place for that, but I could be wrong.  I'm voting too broad for now.

Comment: more like a list of things that fits please

Comment: Expanding on the type of character you intend to play would dramatically improve this question. A list of 50 things is a bit excessive for this site, but if you wanted a means to draw power from your enemies a martial class using psionics or something, that list becomes a lot more manageable.

Answer (score 4):

#### You probably want the Souldrinker prestige class.

The [Souldrinker](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/PrestigeClassesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Souldrinker) gets an at-will energy drain touch attack which gives negative levels. Giving foes negative levels grants you temporary HP as well as soul points, which can be spent for various benefits.

Comment: sounds really cool, but do you know if my familliar can transmit the touch attacks ?

Comment: @anonyme No, your cacodaemon familiar will not be able to transmit the energy drain touch attack.